# Grammatically equivalent sentences, for use in symbolic logic

Tags: syntactic-analysis, predicate

Initially posted to Math Stack Exchange: [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132152)

I believe that English grammar expertise is needed as well.

Is the statement:

> *No student is friendly but not helpful.*

Equivalent to:

A

> There does not exist a person such that that person is a student, that person is friendly, and that person is not helpful.

or

B

> For all people, if a person is a student, then that person is not friendly and helpful.

Comment: The _but_ can't be expressed logically; it's just `AND` with a presupposition of surprise (which is not an assertion and therefore has no logical form, and in any event is determined by the context rather than the syntax). The sentence appears to have undergone conjunction reduction, and if you attempt to put back in everything that's been deleted, you get _No student is friendly and no student is not helpful_, which is not what you want. If you intend to use [friendly and not helpful] as a compound predicate with a negative subject, you have to make sure it gets interpreted that way.

Comment: @JohnLawler, to clarify, is the interpretation of the sentence as a compound predicate "friendly but not helpful" and a negative subject "No student" a reasonable interpretation of the sentence, or is the only reasonable interpretation "No student is friendly and no student is not helpful." And if A is not a valid conclusion, then is B invalid as well? Thanks!

Comment: Your link appears to be to math.SE, not MathOverflow. There, you ask about 'logically equivalent', here, about 'grammatically equivalent'. What does 'grammatically equivalent' mean?

Comment: @anemone Thanks for noting the error, I have corrected this. I understand grammatically equivalent is not a well defined term (i.e. I made it up to try and convey my question). What I mean precisely is: if the rules of English grammar are applied in parsing the sentences are they logically equivalent.  John Lawler interpreted this correctly when he stated that the sentence "appears to have undergone conjunction reduction..."

Comment: No they are not equivalent. Any proposition with more than one operator (Modal, Negative, or Quantifier -- the constituents that bind a focus and have a scope) is extremely likely to be ambigous. If you want it to mean ¬(∃x: `Student`(x)) (`Friendly`(x) ∧ ¬ (`Helpful`(x))) unambiguously, you'll hafta take steps to make sure it does.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not grammatical in English (I don't know why).  Your two renderings into pseudo-English are logically equivalent.

Comment: Do you have any sense of how the initial sentence violates the rules of English grammar? Other than the potentially implied double negative as noted by @JohnLawler

Comment: It's improved by changing "not helpful" to "unhelpful" and "but" to "yet": ?"No student is friendly yet unhelpful."  Maybe it's a combination of oddities that add up to complete awfulness.

Comment: Thanks! For the record that was my contention (this was part of a question on a test).

Answer (score 1):

Your example is the 'normal English' equivalent of A.

B appears to be an unfortunate confusion between English and logic: the first half is too formal to be used outside a textbook, while the second shows the confusion between *(not friendly) and (helpful)* and *not (friendly and helpful)* that English deals with by context and tone, but logic requires to be disambiguated. It is also the opposite of what appears to be intended; replacing the *and* with *or* would solve this problem but not the first one.